# Unusual behaviour with scanf

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf

I am trying to scan a string, it needs to have a max length of 10.

```
struct Person{
        char name[MAX];
        float score;
        date_t dafe;
    };

//MAX = 11
```

I am using a menu and when the string entered is less than 10 characters it works fine but when the string is longer it iterates through the menu and stores the rest of the string (anything past 10 characters) in the name value for the next student in the array (creating a new student). What am I doing wrong? Is this the correct way to limit a string with scanf?

```
while(choice != 6){
    printMenu();
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice){
        case 1 : 
            if(Size < MAX){
                printf("Adding Person \n");
                personList[Size] = addPerson();
                Size++;
            }else{
                printf("Reached maximum size \n");
            }
            break;
        case 2 : //Other Options


Person_t addperson(void){
    person_t tempperson;

    printf("Enter name> \n");
    scanf("%10s", tempPerson.name);
    printf("Enter date: day> \n");
    scanf("%d", &person.date.day);
    //more values

    return tempPerson;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `MAX_NAME_SIZE`?

Comment: It's commented in the first code block, 11

Comment: And so it is!  Suggest `#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 11` prior to `struct student{...`.  Code speaks louder than comments.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind for the future, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What am I doing wrong?*

In case your input is longer than the maximum field width, then, the excess entries present in the input buffer stays there to be read in the next call. So, after scanning, you need to clear off the input buffer off the remaining input before you proceed for the next input.

A rough way of achieving that would be `while ('\n' != getchar());` but with this you'll have a problem for the cases where the input is <= 10 chars.

A better way is to read a whole line using [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets), then use [`sscanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) to read-in the exact input you need.

Comment: Note that the loop needs to capture that character (in an `int`!) so you can test for EOF too.  EOF can occur before the newline; then you have an infinite loop.